# Give table cells rounded corners (or the contents)

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Is it possible to give table cells, or their contents, rounded edges in CSS.

I have not included code as it would just be a blank table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It works pretty much as you’d expect so long as the borders aren’t collapsed.

```css
td {
    border: 0.1em solid black;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

[**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/n14ye7nk/)

How good you can make it look is another matter entirely =)

Comment: hehehe thanks, Is there a way to fill the outline that you have created with a colour?

Comment: Your link is a 404.

Comment: @RolandiXor: Oh, Dabblet appears to have lost some old submissions. It’s nothing special, though, just a demo. Replaced with a new link.

Answer (score 1):

@minitech is correct, so: if you are using `table{border-collapse: collapse;}`, you could wrap the content of your `td`'s in a `div`, for example, and then apply the rounded corners to the `div`:

Example, please see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BKbV9/):

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;}
table{border-spacing: 0;}
td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.with
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.with td
{

    border: 0;
}
.with td > div
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```